# difference between symbolic reference and hard reference in perl

Tags: perl, use-strict

I have been using hard reference in perl. But was thinking in what way symbolic reference can 
be helpful to programmers.

```
           no strict "ref";
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Symbolic reference can "help" you to add bugs to your code. Read [Why it's stupid to `use a variable as a variable name'](http://perl.plover.com/varvarname.html) or [my own experience](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1065867) for reasons why not to use it.